# javascript: how to cope with "@" and ":" in Json

Tags: javascript, json

There is a json data:

```
var json = {  
    "entry" : [{ 
        "category" : {
            "@scheme" : "http:\/\/www.douban.com\/2007#kind", 
            "@term" : "http:\/\/www.douban.com\/2007#movie"
        }, 
        "title" : {
            "$t" : "Real Steel"
        },
        "db:attribute" : [{
            "$t" : "USA", 
            "@name" : "country"
        }]
    }]
}
```

`alert(json.entry[0].title.$t)`  can print "Real Steel". However,
how to get the `http:\/\/www.douban.com\/2007#kind` and `USA`  in Javascript　？

It contains `@` and `:`, I don't know how to cope with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use square brackets and a string instead of `.`

```
json.entry[0].category["@scheme"]
json.entry[0].category["@term"]
json.entry[0]["db:attribute"][0].$t
json.entry[0]["db:attribute"][0]["@name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can do the following:

```
json.entry[0].category["@scheme"]
```